# How add "name" column to table created gem divise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when gem 'devise' install, he's create form with three field in form for sign up (email, password, confirm password). It`s possible added column 'name' for he's form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: create column name for registration form

Comment: sorry for bad language

Comment: I think you need to create a new migration to update your db schema, though I'm not 100% what the question is asking.

Comment: I install gem 'devide' When you create a new user,it has three field in he's form(email, password, confirm password) i need field name. And that would work validation

Answer (score 0):

Is possible just create table attribute in devise User table like:

```
t.string :name
```

and migrate  and install all view using 
    command : `rails generate devise:views users` 
    and the go to devise/registration/new file add following line

```
 <%= f.label :name %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
```

then it display name field when user registration form or sign_up form .

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Devise wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address) or [view railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/210-customizing-devise)